# Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-identity, data-protection

I am running a B2B website, where customers login, view the catalog and place orders. The website runs on
a sub-domain (I think this is an important side note because of [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/11857)). By the time customers finish their order and click on the place order button, they are sent back to the login screen, loosing their order. Sometimes, this period is shorter sometimes longer. Something to do with the Application Pool being restarted?.

So I created a logging functionality to see what's happening and came to find out whenever a user logs in, the following logs are created:

```
Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.

Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.

No XML encryptor configured. Key {6a86c315-5115-4d16-a3f8-2ec49450b794} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
```

I searched these and found a [webpage](https://cypressnorth.com/web-programming-and-development/solved-using-memory-repository-keys-will-not-persisted-storage-asp-net-core-iis/) explaining in detail why this happens. The prblem being a bug in IIS (which it is unlikely to be [corrected](https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/issues/102)) solution is to change a setting on IIS which I am not able to do. I am on a shared hosting. I've already discussed this with their support and they said they cannot change the settings on IIS for shared servers. So, setting the `Load User Profile` to `True` on IIS is not an option for me.

I also read somewhere that using Azure Apps I can change where the keys generated are stored. I have not looked into this yet though.

So any ideas how this issue might be resolved? Is a dedicated server or using Azure services my only options?

For reference, below is the related section from my `Startup.cs` file

```
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

        // lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // sign in settings
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        // user settings
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = System.TimeSpan.FromDays(45);
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
```

Comment: Did you have a look at any other key storage providers you could use in your scenario? E.g. [persisting them to a database system using EF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#entity-framework-core)

Comment: I did not have any clue about it until you mentioned. The problem is now solved using your suggestion. Thank you but can you convert this into an answer so I can accept for future comers to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are unable to use any of the default key persistence methods, there are other options available, e.g. storing the key in a Database (via Entity Framework), Redis, Services like Azure KeyVault etc.

See [Key Storage Providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers) for more details.